# How to get Agent ID in Sabre Central?

Tags: sabre

how to get an Agent ID to log in to Sabre Red 360?

I registered to Sabre Devs but nothign is happening.

Could you help me how to register and connect to Sabre Red 360?
I am a new suer and want to know how to use that CRS to be more efficient and more recognasible by adding new Tour Operators to my offer.